# How can I sign an Ardor transaction using an offline computer?

Tags: ardor

I would like to generate the transaction json on an online computer. Send it to the offline computer without blockchain, sign it. Send the signed json to an online computer and broadcast it.

Answer (score 1):

On the offline computer use the sign.bat / sign.sh script:

```
Usage: SignTransactionJSON <unsigned transaction json file> <signed transaction json file>
```